# What is dev_id parameter in request_irq?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, interrupt

In the function declaration

```
int request_irq(unsigned int irq,
                irqreturn_t (*handler)(int, void *, struct pt_regs *),
                unsigned long irqflags,
                const char *devname,
                void *dev_id);
```

Is `dev_id` an 'in' parameter or an 'out' parameter ?
Where do we get this number from ?

Comment: I updated my ans, see the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dev_id` is an input argument and must be globally unique. Normally the address of the device data structure is used as the `Dev_id`.
It has value `NULL` if the interrupt line is NOT shared. It holds relevance only when the interrupt line is being shared. When it is shared, this parameter uniquely identifies the `interrupt handler` on the shared IRQ.

*But lately in order to process interrupts faster, the linux kernel has moved to `request_threaded_irq`.*

For eg, in the linux kernel, i2c driver for wm8903 audio codec uses this API in the following manner - using `request_threaded_irq()` but use of dev_id is identical.

the device struct is:

```
117 struct wm8903_priv {
118         struct wm8903_platform_data *pdata;
119         struct device *dev;
120         struct snd_soc_codec *codec;
121         struct regmap *regmap;
122 
123         int sysclk;
124         int irq;
125 
126         int fs;
127         int deemph;
128 
129         int dcs_pending;
130         int dcs_cache[4];
131 
132         /* Reference count */
133         int class_w_users;
134 
135         struct snd_soc_jack *mic_jack;
136         int mic_det;
137         int mic_short;
138         int mic_last_report;
139         int mic_delay;
140 
141 #ifdef CONFIG_GPIOLIB
142         struct gpio_chip gpio_chip;
143 #endif
144 };
```

The handler defines a pointer to this struct:

```
2029         struct wm8903_priv *wm8903; //this is the dev_id parameter
```

And then calls the `request_threaded_irq`(),

```
 ret = request_threaded_irq(i2c->irq, NULL, wm8903_irq,
2156                                            trigger | IRQF_ONESHOT,
2157                                            "wm8903", wm8903);
```

[lxr code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/soc/codecs/wm8903.c#L2155)